# How do we access individual signals that are grouped into a bus: input[4:0] in1; in verilog

Tags: verilog, bus

I need to burst

```
input [4:0] in1;
```

into subparts so that i can display every bit separately.I don't know how i can do it.

the signals should be accessed like this

```
input in1:0
input in1:1
input in1:2
input in1:3
```

or in a similar manner but not be in the form of a bus.

Edited:

This is as per limitation of a synthesis tool.In that tool after synthesis in the netlist generated, is like this

```
module test ( in1, in2, out);
input [3:0] in1;
input [3:0] in2;

output [4:0] out;
```

so i want yo ask that what is the alternate way of writing

```
input [3:0] in1;
    input [3:0] in2;

    output [4:0] out;
```

ofcourse not in bus([4:0]) form but bursted or in blast form.

Comment: What do you mean by 'display every bit separately'?  It sounds like you are trying to work around a limitation in your simulator; is that right?

Comment: no, i am just trying to remove the limitation.Actually in every module in my tool, we use to have bus, like i explained in my question.So instead of writing input [4:0] in; , i want to write every bit seprately means for first input bit of in1, second bit of in1, 3rd bit of in1, 4th bit of in1.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean accessing an element in the array, then it should be more like this

For structural modeling

```
module input_set 
     ( input wire [4:0] in,
       output wire out
     );

out = in[0]


endmodule
```

or

```
module input_set 
     ( input wire in0, in1, in2, in3,
       output wire out
     );

output = in0


endmodule
```

In behvioral modeling it is common to use always, but the main difference is the continuous assignments.

```
module input_set 
     ( input reg [4:0] in,
       output reg out
     );

always @ (in[0], in[1], in[2], in[3])
assign output = in[0]


endmodule
```

**Background Knowledge:**

In general there are two main groups of data types: **Net** and **Variable**. I just showed you how to use one type of Net data (*wire*). 
The variable types are *reg*, *Integer*, *Real*, *Time*, and *Realtime*

We use continuous assignments for Net data types and procedural assignments for Variable data types.

You should read about the different types of modeling: Structural, Behavioral and User-Defined Primitives (UDP)
I'd recommend reading some books, here's a good one [http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Digital-Design-Verilog-Edition/dp/0136019285/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1371727816&sr=8-5&keywords=verilog](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136019285)

Comment: i dont understand when people are replying, how others can't understand the same question......this is really bad..

Comment: @shailendra Is this a 4x1 or a 4x4 bus?

Comment: its 4x1 bus, i am not sure though.

Comment: @shailendra It would help if you mentioned some context, so others could understand it. Not everyone uses the same tools or languages.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh:I am using a synthesis tool as i described above in the problem statement.All i want to do is to split pins connections from bus to separate individual pins.As i am new to verilog, there is something called blasting a bus or bursting a bus.I asked in that context , thathow we can perform the operation of blasting a bus i.e. in my case it is input [3:0] in2; in seprate individual pins.

Comment: @shailendra So it would be good to mention Verilog, and this context, by editing the question.

Comment: @echad: As in the my question , my original output with bus was input [3:0] in1;, so is there no requirement of using input when we burst the bus and split it, like input in[1]= 0, and what if there are more than 1 input than how would we differentiate between them?

Comment: @echad: and my main context to ask this question is , i understand that input [3:0] in1; means 4 bit data input bus, but is there any other way to write this like wise splitting input bus

Comment: @shailendra You need to clarify what you mean by _any other way_ or better yet explain the problem as a whole. So if you want to try an alternative way, then do procedural assignments. Try looking into the difference between **Structural Modeling** and **Behavioral modeling**